# Flash 11 swf thumbnail retrieving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

I use to take screenshot from swf to make thumbnails of a converted pdf. It all worked well using BitmapData.draw until flash 11 which gives me the same page on all thumbs.

[image: http://imgur.com/A9BB6]

I'm not quite sure what is handled differently in flash 11 but the bitmapData are all equivalent so its truly something around gotoAndStop that is not the same.

Anybody as an idea on how to solve this ? I could use a totally different way of displaying thumbnails the problem is displaying them.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a bit about this? Flashplayer 11 had some very cool BitmapData API updates. Are you using lock() + unlock()?